# Trouble with jQuery resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a jQuery function which, on window resize, performs the following task:

If window width *increases*, call `profdisplayer` function.  If window width *decreases* call `profhider` function.

I don't know what is wrong with this and how to resolve this.

```
 $(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var awidth = $(window).width();
    var bwidth=0;
    if (awidth>bwidth)
        {   profdisplayer();
            bwidth = awidth;
        }
    if (bwidth>awidth)
    {
        profhider();
        bwidth=awidth;
        }
    });
```

Comment: bwidth is never initiallized?

Comment: @lwo Kucharski sorry it was mistakenly removed, check update..

Comment: Variable bwidth will reset to 0 everytime this routine runs. One solution mat be to initialize bwidth outside the resize routine as a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than declaring bwidth inside resize event declare it outside/globally

```
var bwidth = 0;
$(window).on('resize', function(event){
    var awidth = $(window).width();
    if (awidth>bwidth)
        {   profdisplayer();
            bwidth = awidth;
        }
    if (bwidth>awidth)
    {
        profhider();
        bwidth=awidth;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize bwidth the first time the page loads, in the document ready event.
And don't forget to remove the bwidth declaration from the function.

`var bwidth = $(window).width();`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (awidth>bwidth) // all time false

if (awidth>bwidth) // all time false
```

Your function does nothing.

Comment: if (awidth>bwidth) // not false

if (bwidth>awidth)// not false